# What happens to returned (and none returned) Objects in memory?

Tags: java

This question is regarding Java, and how Objects are created, passed, and "deleted".

From what I know, when you want to create an object, you use the "new" keyword. From my understanding, this operator (new) allocates memory for the object, and the = operator assigns the reference to the location of this object in memory, to the variable name you give it.

For example, let's say you create an array in Java like so.

```
int[] arrayX = new int[size];
```

the `=` operator now stores the reference to the array in memory to the variable name `arrayX`.

This is all fine.

Now let's think about methods (functions).

Firstly, from my understanding, when you call a method, memory is allocated on the stack for this method's variables and processes, and when the method returns, it's instance on the stack is closed/deleted/put in garbage. However, this doesn't explain how you can return objects (such as arrays) which were created in the method back to the caller's scope using the return keyword.

From what I understand, since the method is returning, the data in its stack is going to be deleted. Therefore, the array that was created within this method's scope, will also be deleted. So the reference returned to the array's location, will point to "garbage" values. However, this is clearly not the case. In Java, if you return an Object, you can keep using it.

This makes me confused about how Objects are created, stored and returned...

- are objects created always stored in permanent memory? or
- does the `return` operator move the array or object from the method's temporary stack to the caller's stack?
- if the second case is true, then are objects created within methods deleted after the method returns to the caller (but does not return the object)? In this third case, it would mean that one shouldn't worry about creating objects in methods, as those objects will be deleted. Thus, if a program was to call a method 1000 times, we shouldn't worry about the memory filling up with objects that we only use once.

I have looked through courses offered on edX on Java and even read a book (although not finished) and still haven't found an answer to this so I would appreciate your input (if you know).

EDIT: Please note, this questions asks 3 separate things:
1. Where are Objects and primitives stored
2. what does the new operator do specifically
3. what does the return operator do

Comment: The array isn't created on the stack, only the reference to it. The array is in the managed heap (which is handled by the VM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this doesn't explain how you can return objects (such as arrays) which were created in the method back to the caller's scope using the return keyword

The reason you can do it is that the object is not created on the stack; only the reference to it is. The array stays in the dynamically allocated memory until it becomes eligible for garbage collection. When you assign the result returned from a method to another variable or to a field, the value of the reference is preserved, so the object stays in memory.

> does the return operator move the array or object from the method's temporary stack to the caller's stack?

Only the value of the reference gets copied. The reference is a relatively small object, whose size depends only on the system on which JVM is running. In particular, the size of the reference does not change with the size of the object being referenced, so the amount of required copying is limited.

Answer (score 0):

One important point to note is that if you return an object in a method and don't save it, it does in fact get garbage collected. For example if you have:

```
public int somemethod(){
    int myint = 9;
    return myint;
}
```

And then call `someMethod()` in your main method, in order to access this return for the future you have to store it.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    this.someMethod(); //can't access myInt.
    int savedInt = someMethod(); // Saves the value 9 for future access.
}
```

So in general when you call a method and then the return type is present before that method gets removed from the stack, but in order to use it in the future you must store the value in a variable that will still be present.

Comment: Primitives are stored on the stack, so no garbage collection there. Also you can't call `this` on a static method.